# How to get navigation bar on the banner?

Tags: html, css

I would like the navigation bar to be on the banner? Is this possible. I have been doing the following css to try to achieve and it works but it goes beyond the scope of the wrapper. Here are the following css:

```
 .navbar-buttons{
    padding-top:10px;
    padding-right:20px;
    text-align:right;
    list-style:none;
    margin:0 auto;
    overflow:hidden;
    <!---I commented it out because like I mentioned above, goes out of scope--->
    <!---background-image: url(./img/Intranet_Banner.jpg);--->
    width:100%;
}

#wrapper {
    width: 940px;
    height:100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
 }
```

Following is html page navpage:

```
<div id="wrapper">

<!-- content-wrap starts here -->
<div id="content-wrapper">      

    <img src="img/Banner.jpg" alt="Banner" class="no-border img-banner" />

            <!-- Menu Tabs -->
        <ul>
            <li class="navbar-buttons"><a href="index.cfm"><span>Home</span></a>&nbsp;<span style="color:blue !important">|</span>&nbsp;<a href="Resources.cfm"><span>IT Support</span></a></li>

        </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: "Is it possible?" should really be eliminated from your phrasebook. Aside from that, please be more specific as to what you're trying to achieve here. "On the banner" isn't very specific. Also, CSS comments are `/* Comment */`, not `<!-- Comment -->`

Comment: @Wes Foster: What I mean is the links of the navigation bar is on the image. So the image is the background of the navigation bar which I can achieve but the issue is it goes out of scope. And thank you for your suggestion

Comment: @ Wes Foster: Yes you are correct about the comments for css but it is done in the html page because I am not sure how to use Coldfusion and link the css files to the cfm files yet

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `background-image` property to set a `background-image` on `#content-wrapper`, instead of trying to move your list on top of the .image.

I made a few adjustments to your code:

```css
.navbar-buttons {
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
}
#content-wrapper {
  background-image: url('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/93/Long_sky_background_%2B_PAN.jpg');
}
#wrapper {
  width: 940px;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
a {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">

  <!-- content-wrap starts here -->
  <div id="content-wrapper">
    <!-- Menu Tabs -->
    <ul>
      <li class="navbar-buttons"><a href="index.cfm"><span>Home</span></a>&nbsp;<span style="color:white !important">|</span>&nbsp;<a href="Resources.cfm"><span>IT Support</span></a>
      </li>

    </ul>
  </div>

</div>
```

[View on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qxamuvrx/1/)

Comment: Thanks @Anthony, it helped.

Comment: No problem. Glad it helped